# Why capifony creates both folder /shared/app/logs and /shared/logs (symfony2)

Tags: deployment, symfony, capifony

I use Capifony to deploy my Symfony2 project to the production server. As a result of the deploy:setup task, folder called /shared/logs were created. However the symfony2 actually refers to /shared/app/logs to store the log files while the shared/logs remains empty.

Anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared/logs` folder is no more created since capifony version `2.1.7`.

Answer (score -1):

I've just checked the latest capistrano deploy recipe in [trunk](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb) and it seems like this's a default behaviour of Capistrano instead of Capifony. It create folders using only the last part of the path of the shared_children array instead of including the full path. Later on in the task deploy:shared_children of Capfifony it create the sub folders with full path.

Comment: This is actually wrong, I overrided the task to avoid creating these folders: https://github.com/everzet/capifony/commit/b326293b609dda2d66200b299b4b3d3075de7a19. And, it's part of the 2.1.7 release.

Comment: Yep I just checked the link you sent, you are right, thanks for that ;)